# Remove the required elements of string2 from string1

Tags: c++, string, std

Consider 2 strings string1 and string2.
The main objective of my code is to remove only  elements of string 2 from string 1.
Here's my code

```
 string sring1,string2;
    cin>>string1>>string2;
     for(int i = 0; i<string2.length(); i++){
         
     string1.erase(std::remove(string1.begin(), string1.end(),string2.at(i) ), string1.end());
     }
cout<<string1;
```

The problem with the above code is that, its removing all the elements of string2 in string1 whereas I want to remove just the particular elements of string2 from string1 leaving the rest as it is
Here is sample output
INPUT: abbccdef 
abc
REQUIRED OUTPUT : bcdef
MY OUTPUT: def

CONSTRAINTS:1≤|string2|≤|string1|≤10^5 
Please help in modifying my code.

Comment: Please provide any alternative solution for this.

Comment: > *I want to remove just the particular elements of string2 from string1 leaving the rest as it is*. What particular elements??

Comment: Means just the elements in string2...like we have 2 characters like of 'a' in string1 and string2 has only 1 of 'a' ...then delete just one character in string1..leaving the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s1 = "abbccdef";
    std::string s2 = "abc";

    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s2.length(); ++i) {
        for (std::string::size_type j = 0; j < s1.length(); ++j) {
            if (s1[j] == s2[i]) {
                s1.erase(j, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
 # ./a.out 
 bcdef
```

### EDIT

OP has modified the question and now looking for an optimal solution of this problem.

Solution:

1. Record the number of occurrence of characters of string2 in an array.
2. Parse the string1 and if character found in the array, decrease it's count and erase it from string1.

Assume size of string1 is `n` and size of string2 is `m` then complexity of this solution is `O(n+m)` as both the strings parsed only once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string s1 = "abbccdef";
    std::string s2 = "abc";
    std::vector<int> count(128, 0);

    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s2.length(); ++i) {
        ++count[s2[i]];
    }

    std::string::size_type j = 0;
    while (j < s1.length()) {
        if (count[s1[j]] != 0) {
            --count[s1[j]];
            s1.erase(j, 1);
            continue;
        }
        ++j;
    }

    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
bcdef
```

Comment: @AbhijitUtkarsh What exactly mean by _"can we do more better"_? Please elaborate.

Comment: Let say we have a constraint 1≤|string2|≤|string1|≤10^5...will this code will able to run on that? as its using two for loops? Please me correct if I am wrong.

Comment: In your question you have not mentioned anything about the optimal code. In fact, in your first comment in your question you asked about any alternative solution. Of course using two loop Is not the optimal solution.

Comment: Ya ,can you give any optimal way to approach this problem

Comment: @AbhijitUtkarsh Updated answer with an optimal solution. Check EDIT.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `string1` contains all the characters from `string2`, you could do:

```
int pos = 0;  // keep track of last deleted char position

for(auto c : string2)
    string1.erase(pos = string1.find(c, pos), 1);  // update new pos and erase char
```

This does a single linear pass over both strings. If you have characters in `string2` that are not in `string1`, you can add an additional check for `std::string::npos`.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sMPTfK).